# MVC upload file BeginForm HTTPPOST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, file-io

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to my controller to proccess the data.

This is in my MVC razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddManyDevices", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     <input id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" type="file" />
     <input id="subButton" type="submit" value="FileUpload" class="btn btn-success" title="Upload File" />
}
```

This is my method in `HomeController`, one method to return view and one to handle HTTP POST

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AddManyDevices()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public void AddManyDevices(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
{
   StreamReader csvreader = new StreamReader(FileUpload.InputStream);

   while (!csvreader.EndOfStream)
   {
       var line = csvreader.ReadLine();
       var values = line.Split(';');
   }
}
```

However when I upload a file the HTTP POST `AddManyDevices` is not called, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Lanorkin, that's not necessarily true. The `ActionInvoker` would automatically return `EmptyResult` from `void` methods.

Comment: I don't need a return value right now, the method isn't even called. Changing from void to ActionResult does't solve my problem.

Comment: I tried your code in my application , your action is being called .

Comment: What do you see in browser network panel (F12 tools), when you click submit button? Which URL, which METHOD, which status code, body?

Comment: a GET with statuscode 200 to AddManyDevices?FileUpload=test.csv
/Home is done... hmm?

Comment: Can you attach relevant HTML which were generated for form (using view source)? Is it the same behavior for all browsers, or just specific one?

Comment: I just solved it by removing  new {@enctype = "multipart/form-data" }

Comment: Actually no... now i get that FileUpload is null. This is the generated html

Comment: <form action="/Home/AddManyDevices" method="post">                                        <input id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" type="file" />
                                        <input id="subButton" type="submit" value="FileUpload" class="btn btn-success" title="Upload File" />
</form>

Comment: I think, the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` is essential here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the @ symbol from the `@enctype = "multipart/form-data"`

and use like below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddManyDevices", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```